# Weight in scrollview

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a task - make an activity like this [image: task] Here photo takes one half of screen and text takes another. And everything works fine with weights, but sometimes text can take a lot of space and don't fit in screen, so I covered all my layout with ScrollView, but here comes problem. If everything doesn't fit into one screen everything should look that way - photo will take one half of visible screen and second half will contain some part of text that can fit there, and when I scroll, everything should be scrolled and new text will appear at the bottom. But I don't understand how to realize that, weights here work in some weird way and as I understood tag `fillViewPort="true"` makes something only if there is nothing to scroll, and when there is something this tag makes nothing. So how can I make my view look in proper way?

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="leopikinc.musiciansyandex.MusicianInfo"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/big_photo"
            android:src="@drawable/test"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Genres"
            android:id="@+id/genres"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Album count"
            android:id="@+id/album_count"
            android:layout_below="@+id/genres"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Track count"
            android:id="@+id/track_count"
            android:layout_above="@+id/biography_string"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/album_count"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/album_count" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/biography_string_text"
            android:id="@+id/biography_string"
            android:layout_below="@+id/album_count"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Biography Text"
            android:id="@+id/biography_text"
            android:layout_below="@+id/biography_string"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I don't exactly understand the last part but for solving this issue you could try this logic.    1. You have your root layout which I assume is a linear layout with the weight property setup.     2.You have your image view.      3. Now instead of just putting a scroll view put your scroll view inside a linear layout. Just the scroll view and inside a new linear layout

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: @KISHORE_ZE I'm not native speaker sorry). I want my view look like on picture even if the text is huge. So view simly must be scrollable.

Comment: I can't see a single line related to weights implementation in your xml

Comment: and KISHORE_ZE way is probably what you need to do

Comment: @Leopik No problem so what you can do is put your relative layout in a scroll view or am I still not getting it. Sorry :)

Comment: @KISHORE_ZE if I put relative layout in scrollview, scrolled will be only TextView and image won't be scrolled, but I want to scroll whole screen

Comment: @VivekMishra I removed this tags, but there were `android:weight="1"` in RelativeLayout and in LinearLayout

Comment: So what happens with your current code? Sorry. :) What error happens with this code? By text is huge do you mean the size of text? Thanks. I may have to come back after an hour or 2 so if in unresponsive I'll do it soon.

Comment: @KISHORE_ZE it means amount of text that is to be scrolled is huge

Comment: @VivekMishra If the whole thing is under a scroll view then won't it get scrolled?

Comment: yes it will get scrolled

Comment: @VivekMishra so what's the issue?

Comment: @KISHORE_ZE Here is video how it looks now https://youtu.be/N6DnKMMm-GA

Comment: I am not saying any issue I was just explaining what OP wants to say

Comment: @Leopik Oh OK. Thanks. I may be offline for an hour. So quickly try these things. In your image view try adding scale type as centreCrop or try changing your gravity to center|top. These will probably not fix it but help us understand the issue. So try these out one at a time and tell me the result after each change. Thanks! Post it and I'll check it after an hour.  :)

Comment: @KISHORE_ZE here is with centercrop https://youtu.be/_nL0VA6nwxY
and with center|top nothing changed

Comment: But isnt the extra space now gone?

Comment: no, there is still extra space on top and on bottom. I think I should add that size of bitmap is 1000x1000

Comment: @KISHORE_ZE I achived my aim making it programmaticaly. In activity i got access to ImageView and set it's height = half of visible screen.




`ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = bigphoto.getLayoutParams();
lp.height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels/2;
bigphoto.setLayoutParams(lp);`

Comment: Here how it looks. But still I have a question, how can I do this using XML?
https://youtu.be/PBsc0g8ERkU

Comment: Not really sure. Post your solution as an answer and mark it as correct. As for in xml. Try this get the value of getDisplayMetrics().heightpixels by setting that value to an int and then parse it to string and finally log or toast the value to find the value and now you can easily set the value manually. However if different images have different sizes programmatically doing it is probably better. Hope at least this helps you. I feel I have done really bad with this question:)

Comment: @KISHORE_ZE but if I set the value manually, on other devices that will take not half of the screen but more or less

Comment: True. So probably doing it programmatically would be best. Try this in your Linear Layout which has `tools:context="leopikinc.musiciansyandex.MusicianInfo"` add layout_weight="2" and add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achived my aim making it programmaticaly. In activity I got access to ImageView and set it's height = half of visible screen.

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = bigphoto.getLayoutParams(); 
lp.height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels/2;
bigphoto.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

But still I don't know how to make this using XML

Comment: No Problem. Sorry I couldn't help much.